# How to make input type list only accept a list choice?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, list, input

I want user to select a state just from this list :

```
<input list="states">
<datalist id="states">
    <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
    <option value="Frenada">Frenada</option>
    <option value="Finalizada">Finalizada</option>
</datalist>
```

but also I don't want to use <select>, i know that but I want to keep the ability to type (and search among the options) but at last, one of the options must be selected.
please help me with this. I want to use it in react

Comment: What (I think) you’re after is called [*typeahead*](https://swiftype.com/search-concepts/typeahead) - try doing some searching on this

Answer (score 2):

You can set the *value* attribute of the input with the option *value* you want to be selected:

```html
<input list="states" value="Pendiente">
<datalist id="states">
    <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
    <option value="Frenada">Frenada</option>
    <option value="Finalizada">Finalizada</option>
</datalist>
```